# Why is my preg_match result getting doubled?

Tags: php

Slowly, but surely, I'm assembling a website for personal usage where I search for the name of a movie and it returns me the metacritic rating of it. Here's what I got so far:

```
$web = file_get_contents("http://www.metacritic.com/movie/the-lion-king"); 

preg_match(
    '/<span class="score_value" property="v:average">(.*?)<\/span>/s',
    $web,
    $match
 );

foreach ($match as $score) {
    $sc = $score;
    echo $sc;
}
```

Result:

```
8383
```

Where it should return only 83 and not 8383.

I pointed the way to where the metacritic rating is located because I need to grab that information. I'm not sure whether or not it's correct? May be some very crude work, I don't understand preg_match very well, the documentation online did not help a bit.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/576139

Comment: Gosh, so regex can't parse html? Thanks Chris!

Comment: Since you're new to SO I'm going to give you a friendly suggestion.  You should choose an answer below to accept.  I'm going to recommend Krister's since that answer was posted before mine and is just as valid.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Tim, I did accept his answer. I couldn't do it before because there was a timer, silly timer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should only echo out `$score[1]` because that is where your first captured parenthesized subpattern will go.

Read documentation for [preg_match](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php)

Comment: So that's where I was wrong, I was doing a loop unnecessarily wasn't I? I'm ashamed. Thank you Krister!!

Answer (score 5):

FYI:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(56) "<span class="score_value" property="v:average">83</span>"
  [1]=>
  string(2) "83"
}
```

[Manual](http://php.net/preg_match) reads:

*If matches is provided, then it is filled with the results of search. $matches[0] will contain the text that matched the full pattern, $matches[1] will have the text that matched the first captured parenthesized subpattern, and so on.*

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhhh, so that's why my loop was doubling it. I don't understand how it showed only 83 for [0], shouldn't it show the whole `"<span class="score_value" property="v:average">83</span>" ` ?

Comment: it did.  but the span is invisible in output. :)  It shows up if you do a view source.

Answer (score 1):

use print_r on matches to be sure but I think it is printing the back-referenced value in parentheses as the second one